# How to avoid writing documentation twice for doxygen and argparse?

Tags: python, module, argparse, doxygen

I'm kind of a newbie in Python and i try to start with good practices. I am currently writing small reusable scripts containing one function and I want them to :

- Generate a doc in doxygen
- Generate help with command line (I am using argparse)
- Be launchable from shell
- Have the main function that can be imported from other scripts

I put bellow what I've ended up with so far.

My main question is : **is there a way to avoid the doc redundancy which has to be written twice ?**

Also, is there any cleaner way to create this kind of versatile scripts ? One of the downfall of this file construction is that if the instructions are split in sub-functions,I hide them all from doxygen in the main function. Which I think is not very elegant...

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    """! Some description
    """
    
    import argparse
    
    def foo(arg1, arg2):
        """!
        @param arg1: arg1 parameter description
        @param arg2: arg2 parameter description
        """
        print("Hello from foo function")
    
    
    ## \cond
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Some description')
    parser.add_argument("arg1", help="arg1 parameter description")
    parser.add_argument("arg2", help="arg2 parameter description")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    ## \endcond
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        foo(parser.arg1, parser.arg2)
```